# Function in constructor initialiser list?

Tags: c++, list, constructor, initialization, initializer

Heyy, I am trying to switch from initialising my variables within the constructor to using the constructor initialiser list.

So instead of writing

```
Class::Class(int width, int height) {
  this->width = width;
  this->height = height;
}
```

I am doing this:

```
Class::Class(int width, int height) : 
  width(width), 
  height(height) {
}
```

That's all working, but now my problem... Say I have the following constructor:

```
Class::Class(int width, int height) {
  this->width = width;
  this->height = height;
  this->state.setCurrState(this->state.stateMenu);
  this->state.setPrevState(this->state.getCurrState());
}
```

"state" is just an object of the class "State" which I create in my header. The functions setCurrState and setPrevState are of the type void and just set the class's private variable.

How do I convert the constructor? I know it is possible to write functions in the initialiser list, but the functions I want to add do not return anything... they are void, so I do not know how I would call them?

```
Class::Class(int width, int height) :
  width(width), 
  height(height) 
  // call functions here... but how?
  {
}
```

Thank you so much I hope you can help me <3

Comment: Does `State` have a constructor taking them?

Comment: @chris The State constructor takes no arguments, there are only the two funtions I mentioned

Comment: Using `this->` when it's not needed is extremely ugly and verbose.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: In the asker's coding style, it will help prevent errors, since member names are not distinguished from regular local variable names except by the `this->` decoration.

Comment: @jxh Oh you're right; at least he's switching to inializer list and the problem disappears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no additional point and advantage to call those functions in initializer list, at least in your case.

Simply call them in the constructor body.

---

Important note:

You said `state` is a member of `Class`. So in constructor's level, `state` is not constructed yet, then constructing it by itself is somehow meaningless:

```
state.setCurrState(state.stateMenu);
state.setPrevState(state.getCurrState());
```

Try to write a well constructor for `state`'s class to set curr/prev to a initial states.

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution: Leave the initializing functions in the body of the constructor.

Slightly more difficult solution:

Add a constructor to State to initialize it from an argument.

Write new functions that return the value that you want to pass to the constructor of State.

Comment: thanks I will call the functions from within the constructor then

Comment: In this case, the "Slightly more difficult solution" is not an option.  He's setting the state using values which are members of that state, which are not legally accessible before that state object is constructed.

Comment: I _said_ it was more difficult (grin). The new constructor has to "do the right thing".   In fact if it may not even need any arguments in which case state can be ignored in the initializer list for Class

Comment: Adding the constructor to `State` is really the only correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

`setCurrState` and `setPrevState` are not *formally* initializing your `state` object, they are merely changing it's "state" (no pun intended) after it has been initialized.

If you consider them to be *semantically* initializing you state object, then you might as well formalize that by incorporating them in state's constructor (which should receive the needed states and set them right away). You can then initialize it in the initializer list.

Answer (score 0):

Add a function that returns a `State`:

```
State GiveMeAState() {
  State state;
  state.setCurrState(state.stateMenu);
  state.setPrevState(state.getCurrState());
}
```

and use it in your initialization list:

```
Class::Class(int width, int height) : 
  width(width), 
  height(height),
  state(GiveMeAState()) {
}
```